# Improve MySQL nested select performance with join

Tags: mysql, performance

I have seen many samples to improve MySQL nested selects with joins, but I can't figure this out for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE answer = 'SuccessSubscribed' AND phone NOT IN 
         (SELECT phone FROM messages WHERE answer = 'SuccessUnSubscribed');
```

the query finds people who have subscribed but never unsubscribed.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`phone` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
`content` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
`flags` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`answer` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
....,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
....
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `NOT IN`, you can use `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check.

```
SELECT M1.*
FROM messages M1
LEFT JOIN messages M2 ON M2.phone = M1.phone AND M2.answer = 'SuccessUnSubscribed'
WHERE M1.answer = 'SuccessSubscribed' AND M2.phone IS NULL
```